# How to move a button above the keyboard?

Tags: android, android-layout

This question has been asked before, but I can't find a good answer that works for me.

Here is my XML code (updated):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Account Name"
        android:textSize="32dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
        android:id="@+id/textView" />

    <EditText
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:id="@+id/accountName"
        android:background="@drawable/edit_text_background"
        android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="15dp"
        android:padding="10dp"
        android:backgroundTint="@color/abc_secondary_text_material_light" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Account Balance"
        android:textSize="32dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"/>

    <EditText
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:inputType="numberDecimal"
        android:id="@+id/accountBalance"
        android:background="@drawable/edit_text_background"
        android:layout_marginRight="15dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
        android:padding="10dp"
        android:backgroundTint="@color/abc_secondary_text_material_light"
        android:text="£"
        />


    <Button
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="20dp"
        android:text="New Button"
        android:id="@+id/button"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        />

</RelativeLayout>
```

I've tried using `android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan|adjustResize"` however it hasn't worked.

I feel I'm doing something wrong with the layout of the XML code... It looks like this and I want the button to move up when the keyboard appears:

[image]

Comment: Take the Xml Code in Scrollview

Comment: Try RelativeLayout as parent.

Comment: Just add `android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan"` to your
 `activity` tag in your manifest file.

Comment: @Ajit I have tried that and it hasn't made a difference to the button... Apart from messing up the stuff at the top (which was expected)

Comment: @Apurva I have the following: `<activity
            android:name="com.mwapps.moneymanager.AddAccount"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan"
            android:label="Money Manager">
        </activity>` and it hasn't made a difference to the button.

Comment: Could it be something to do with `android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"` ?

Comment: You need to use RelativeLayout instead of LinearLayout as root.

Comment: @Apurva even with the relative layout instead of linear and the second relative layout removed the button still isn't moving up. Could it be because of alignParentBottom being used?

Comment: Having button aligned to parentBottom,you cano move the button upwards ,it will mess up the layout in doing so.You can place the button just below the edittext 2 if you button to be visible when usey types in.

Comment: @GyanendraMani is there a way to have the button aligned at the bottom, but then move it up when the keyboard is shown?

Comment: Yes as answered below you can use the scrollview

Answer (score 4, accepted):

try using ScrollView at parent level

```
<ScrollView
            android:id="@+id/login_form"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            >
```

Comment: Scrollview can host only one direct parent, so it would need anther layout underneath... Which should I use?

Comment: under that scroll view you can use one linear layout

Answer (score 1):

in your AndroidManifest.xml

```
android:windowSoftInputMode="stateVisible|adjustResize"
```

in style.xml file set your activity style as

```
<item name="android:windowActionBarOverlay">true</item>
```

make sure you are not using **fullscreen** activity.

Answer (score -1):

I struggled with the same thing for long. The solution worked for me is by

adding below line to activity manifest.

```
android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden"
```

I request to keep the layout inside scrollview except the view(Button in this ques case) which you want move with keyboard.

Comment: it is not the answer for this question at all